# Can't run pod install - permission error

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

I have been trying to run someone's project but can't do pod install.

```
pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `KNMultiItemSelector` from `https://github.com/kentnguyen/KNMultiItemSelector.git`
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (2.5.1)
Installing Amplitude-iOS (2.2.4)
Installing Analytics (1.11.2)
Installing AppsFlyer-SDK (2.5.3.10)
Installing Bugsnag (4.0.3)

[!] Error installing Bugsnag
[!] /usr/bin/git submodule update --init

Submodule 'KSCrashModule' (git@github.com:bugsnag/KSCrash.git) registered for path 'KSCrashModule'
Cloning into 'KSCrashModule'...

Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.



Please make sure you have the correct access rights

and the repository exists.

Clone of 'git@github.com:bugsnag/KSCrash.git' into submodule path  'KSCrashModule' failed
```

I tried a bunch of different suggestions on Stack Overflow etc. and still running into this.  Anyone have some other ideas?

Comment: Can you try running `git clone git@github.com:bugsnag/KSCrash.git` and see if that works by itself? That seems to be what's failing.

Comment: That gives me a permission denied. @KeithSmiley

Comment: It looks like you'll want to make sure your ssh keys are added to GitHub as explained [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the "Bugsnatcher" podfile and reinstalling it.  I had another error with a different podfile afterwards, but also reinstalled that one.  Project built after that.

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem. I follow

1. Checking for existing SSH keys(https://help.github.com/articles/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys/)
2. Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent(https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent)
3. and then enter Correct SSH keys password.
4. "pod install" again, It's work.